# Symfony 3 - Continue the session if the account is disabled in FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

on my site I have users that I manage thanks to FOSUserBundle.

I am using the "enabled" attribute which is part of the FOSUser model.

However, when one of my users is disabled, they can not connect anymore. It will have the message "Your comtpe is disabled".

However, on my site, when a user is disabled, I want to give him the opportunity to connect and view certain pages of the site.

How can I remove this prohibition from logging in after deactivation? Thank you

EDIT :

On my site, the notion of disabled user is different.
A "disabled" user on my site will just lose the ability to use the site normally. He will only have access to his "My Account" space, on which he can redo a request to reactivate his account, which will be studied by the administrator.

He will then receive an email from the administrator with his answer. If his request is accepted, his account will be reactivated and he will be able to use all the functionalities of the site again.

That's why I do not want FOSUserBundle to stop me from logging in when the user is disabled

Comment: The idea of deactivation is what it states. The user is no more active, therefore he or she cannot log in anymore until someone activates it again. I am not sure what do you want to achieve here, so please extend your question so someone can help.

Comment: Why do not use another specific Tag instead of `disabled`? Or another Role?

Comment: Because I manage two User entities (from different authentication mode and different processing) which both have the attribute "enabled" and are treated in the same way (and I use a Line that allows me to intervene on this value whatever the User entity). If I use another attribute, it will force me to change the attribute of the other entity as well, and that will give me too much modification work

Comment: so you want to use the activation feature, but at the same time don't want to use it, while preferably changing nothing. is that correct? because *some* modification is probably necessary to do this logical contradiction.

Comment: Let's say that the "enabled" attribute, if it is false, should not prevent the user from logging in, but just allow me to find out better when I treat users.

Comment: Aha.. So the question is more clear now to me. You can use user roles in that case. When the user registers for the first time, give him a SIMPLE_USER_ROLE, and after that grant him more permissions based on other roles.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the disable functionality is actually part of the Symfony security component, not FOSUserBundle.  You could plug in your own authenticator to disable it and then maybe your own user provider to tweak the roles as suggested above.  But whatever you do will require plenty of mods.